# QT5 and SQLite3 "No query Unable to fetch row"

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5

i have a problem with my SQLite Database in QT5. I have table called "mytable" and im trying to save, change or load data there. The table looks like this (CODE):

```
"mytable" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "name" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "akcie" INTEGER NOT NULL )
```

Then im trying to work with this database like this (CODE):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_save_clicked()
{
    QString jmeno, IDcko, ak;

    IDcko = ui->lineEdit_ID->text();
    jmeno = ui->lineEdit_Name->text();
    ak = ui->lineEdit_Akcie->text();

    open_connection();

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(id= \'"+ IDcko +"\', name= \'"+ jmeno +"\', akcie= \'"+ ak +"\')");

    if(query.exec())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("SAVED"), tr("Some text."));
        close_connection();
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("NOT SAVED"), query.lastError().text());
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

In the same file im opening connection like this (CODE):

```
bool MainWindow::open_connection()
{
    QSqlDatabase database;
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    database.setDatabaseName("‪..\\added\\test_table.sqlite");
    if(!database.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "not opened connection";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "opened connection";
        return true;
    }
}
```

And im still getting error: "No query Unable to fetch row", i have been looking for the answer really hard but nothing worked. Could it be because of some includes or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What does `QSqlQuery::lastError()` say?

Comment: @cmannett85 It still says: "No query Unable to fetch row"

Answer (score 2):

You are not preparing the query right. Use [bindings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html) like:

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(:id, :name, :akcie)");
query.bindValue(":id", IDcko);
query.bindValue(":name", jmeno);
query.bindValue(":akcie", ak);
```

Comment: print out the query you are preparing with `query.executedQuery()`

Comment: @PetrBečka you should use bindings as much as possible anyway to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @Miki query.executedQuery() shows me this: "INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(id= 'idcko', name= 'jm', akcie= 'akc')" and I am using bindValues as you told me..

Comment: remove the (') from the prepare.... that should work.. sorry for the typo. Aslo remove (id=). See update code in the answer

Comment: @Miki Ok, something has changed, my query.prepare() looks exactly like yours and im getting query.lastError() like: " Parameter count mismatch" and my query.executedQuery() is saying: "INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"

Comment: if it was _exactly_ like my code, it won't work. You should put the same number of different placeholders and bindings. Try now with updated code

Comment: Still the same result: " Parameter count mismatch".. Could it be because "id" and "akcie" are defined in "mytable" like INT and im using QString in my code?

Comment: If you are expecting int, use int! Just use QString::number(...). I don't know if it solves the problem, but it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You did not execute the query. You should use bindings like:

```
query.prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
query.addBindValue(IDcko);
query.addBindValue(jmeno);
query.addBindValue(ak); 
query.exec();
```

or, like @Miki mentioned, with the help of `query.bindValue(":id", IDCko)` function.
The last way will be to write the query text straightly (without the need to separately call `query.exec()`:

```
query("INSERT INTO mytable(id, name, akcie) VALUES(id= \'"+ IDcko +"\', name= \'"+ jmeno +"\', akcie= \'"+ ak +"\')");
```