# Qt Sql error coming from nowhere: No query Unable to fetch row

Tags: qt

I have a client connected to a server, and it is also connected to a Sqlite3 database. When I receive a message from the server a get an QMessageBox showing an error

> "No query Unable to fetch row"

I tried it with qDebug() outputs and by Debugging the application but the message is not produced by me nor thrown by any DB execution, since none is executed at the moment when I get the message.

Ok I figured out that the error is shown when I write something to the socket. The error does not affect anything, the program continues to run. Here is the code piece were the error is shown:

```
void ConnectionHandler::sendBytes(QByteArray bytes) {
     QMessageBox::critical(0, "test", "test");
     this->socket->write(bytes);
     this->socket->flush();  // after this call the error message is shown
     this->socket->waitForBytesWritten();
     QMessageBox::critical(0, "test2", "test2");
}
```

I checked the bytes that are supposed to be written but they look like what they are supposed to!?

Screenshot of the error:
[image: image of the error]

Comment: Maybe this helps you: [QT5 and SQLite3 “No query Unable to fetch row”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357534/qt5-and-sqlite3-no-query-unable-to-fetch-row).

Comment: As mentioned I get the error but there is no transaction to the database happening, no SELECT nor INSERT!?. I inserted a breakpoint in the `readyRead` method and before it arrives on that breakpoint I receive the error message...

Comment: Can you add some code and indicate where this error happens? And did you try a really simple program to connect to the database and do the query (i.e. without any external client connections, etc.)? Just to check that part is working.

Comment: I have no idea where the error comes from otherwise this post wouldn't be necessary, so posting the entire code is not possible. I have a server running to which two clients are connected. Both cleints are connected to a Sqlite DB, but not to the same. When one client  sends a message to the other client through the server then the receiver shows the message before the `readyRead` method is even called.

Comment: But where in your code is this specific message (*No query Unable to fetch row*) shown. The `QMessageBox::critical` lines in your `sendBytes` function obviously don't show this. The message it shows you should be sent by some function that does the query call (directly or indirectly), but this cannot be deduced from this code.

Comment: The message is not produced by me otherwise I'd know where it comes from. Between the two message boxes from my code I get this weird one, and I have no idea where it comes from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93076/discussion-between-agold-and-wasp256).